# NW.js build doesn't open for Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-webkit, raspbian, nw.js

I have a desktop application (built with NW.js and the node-webkit-builder) that runs smoothly on Windows and OS X, however, I can't seem to open the executable on the Raspberry Pi. The NW.js builder outputs the 32- and 64-bit Linux distributions, as well, that I assume should operate on Raspbian or [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE). However, I keep getting the error:

> cannot open the application since there isn't a readable executable.

Even after chmod +x the application, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

raspberry pi use arm architecture, you may checkout this: https://github.com/toxygen/armhf-node-webkit

Answer (score 0):

Rasp Pis are using ARM processors and not the x32 and x64 processors the NW.js binaries support.

You will need to download a prebuilt for the ARM or build it yourself.

[Here](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1151#issuecomment-78030735) is a link to a prebuilt for 0.12.0. You will package your app just like you would on a x32/x64 machine.

Unfortunately ARM is still not an officially supported platform and if you wish to have prebuilts you will have to depend on community members/contributors.

Answer (score 0):

You need the binary port of NW.js (node-webkit) for Raspberry Pi.

I have just created a repository with the node-webkit binary port that runs on Raspbian, tested and working on Raspberry Pi 1 and Raspberry Pi 3 so it is ARMv6 and ARMv7 compatible.

Here you can check it: https://github.com/jalbam/nwjs_rpi

Comment: will this run on headless rpi?